# How to troubleshoot .net WinForm dialog localization

Tags: .net, winforms, localization

I have created a dialog box under Visual Studio .NET in C#/Winforms that must support multiple languages.  I have set the dialog **Localizable** property to True, then selected the neutral **Language** - French and entered the French text in the dialog, as well as French (France).  I see the associated resource files:

AboutBox.fr-FR.resx
 AboutBox.fr.resx
 AboutBox.resx

To test it, I set the thread CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture to CultureInfo("fr-FR") in the main thread as shown below, then created the dialog box, but only the English version shows.   I verified that the thread CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture were still set to "fr-FR" during the dialog constructor.

```
            CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

The overall Neutral language for the assembly is English-US.

I cannot see any useful messages in the output window.   What is the best way to track down the reasons for .NET localization runtime behavior?

Comment: How are you setting the cultureinfo. Can you post that exact one line of code ?

Comment: Updated with code sample

Comment: I can't repro your problem with a simple Winforms app that localizes the Text property of a Form.  Which is pretty much the way you trouble-shoot problems like this, if it doesn't work for *one* property then it won't work for the rest of them either.  Saves you the trouble of typing in a whole bunch of property values.  Exactly *why* you can't make it work is completely invisible from the question, maybe you got lost in the forest.

Comment: Can you please revisit the localization steps by following this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was C# code behind overriding the designer fields with English text.   I was trying to run a quick test before finishing the rest of the translations.